# Set the primary key for many to many relationship

Tags: database-design

For the two relations, Customer and Equipment:
There is a limited number of equipments (stock)  and upon hiring I need to store the date of hire and the expected return date.

I sketched this:

```
Table Customer   
customer_id

Table Equipment   
equip_id   
available_stock

Table Hire_Equipment
customer_id
equip_id
hiring_date
expected_return_date
```

What I'm not sure about is what is the primary key of Hire_Equipment?
If it is customer_id and equip_id then the customer wont be able to hire the equipment again in the future?
Did I mis-designed the schema? do you suggest a better approach?

Comment: You can make the `(customer_id, equip_id, hiring_date)` the PK. Then a customer can't hire the same equipment twice in the same day.

Comment: Or you can add a surrogate primary key.

Comment: @ypercube And I guess adding the number of hired equipments to Hire_Equipment table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a practical system (as opposed to a textbook problem) you would want to have some kind of *transaction identifier* on any transaction like hiring one or more pieces of equipment.  Assuming you are running an equipment hiring business, your transactions would probably have to account for letting out multiple pieces of equipment at once.  Therefore you need to add an order table as follows:

```
Table Order
order_id
order_date
```

and your Hire_Equipment table would change as follows:

```
Table Hire_Equipment
customer_id (PK)
order_id (PK)
equip_id (PK)
expected_return_date
```

Note that the `hiring_date` has been normalised up to the `Order` level, but `expected_return_date` has been left at the item level, since you might want to allow a single order to contain a mixture of rental periods.

This design allows a customer to hire a piece of equipment more than once on a given date but it prevents hiring the same equipment more than once on the same order - which is what you would expect.

Comment: Why Order table doesn't have 'customer_id' FK ?

Comment: @Chiron - It depends on your business rules for orders.  If everything on one order must be for the same customer then you should move `customer_id` to the `Order` table instead of `Hire_Equipment`.  Your original model didn't require this restriction even though it is a reasonably common rule, so I didn't presuppose it.

Comment: If I moved customer_id to Order table, what is the primary key of Hire_Equipment ? order_id and equipment_id ?

Comment: @Chiron - Yes, that's right.  Hire_Equipment would be identified by the FKs to Order and to Equipment.